# how to create custom button using  gradient effects?

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-button

how to create such [image]

type of button baground using button selector ?
i add button selector code hare please help me ..

```
<item android:state_enabled="false">
     <shape>
        <gradient
            android:startColor="#B2D570"
            android:endColor="#79B903"
            android:angle="270" />
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#4C5E2E" />
        <corners
            android:radius="2dp" />
        <padding
            android:left="5dp"
            android:top="4dp"
            android:right="5dp"
            android:bottom="4dp" />
    </shape>
 </item>
```

Answer (score 2):

this is the code for selector: this will be useful for u, name this file and put this in xml drawable folder,and set the background of ur button with this filename....

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

  <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

      <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/focused" />

      <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/focusedpressed" />

      <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/pressed" />

      <item android:drawable="@drawable/defaultbutton" />

  </selector>
```

Comment: This sets the image for the button but will not wrap content, like the native background drawable